# Entity Framework REST endpoint to get all entites that have another entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, api

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can return all books that have a rating. For every book, a rating may apply (one-to-zero-or-one relationship).

Book model class:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("isbn")]
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("title")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [MinLength(1)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("author")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [MinLength(1)]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("year_of_publication")]
    public int yearOfPublication { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("publisher")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Rating Rating { get; set; }

}
```

Rating class:

```
 public class Rating
{
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("rating_seq")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [MaxLength(13,ErrorMessage = "ISBN is too long!")]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [DisplayName("book_rating")]
    public int rating { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I should return a list of books that have a rating. Right now I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
[HttpGet("/ratings")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetBooksWithRating()
    {
        var books = await _context.Book
            .Include(l => l.Rating)
            .Where(s => s.Isbn == _context.Rating.Isbn) //not accessible
            .ToListAsync();
        if (books == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return books;
    }
```

Obviously this is false, but any help on how to correct it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this

```
    var books = await _context.Book
        .Include(b => b.Rating)
        .Where(b => b.Rating != null)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Here we tell EF to `Include` the `Rating` navigation property on all the books we retrieve, but only return those books if the `Rating` is not `null` - which would indicate a book without a `Rating`

Comment: Thank you, it works wonders! 
I'd also need an endpoint to get book by ISBN with rating, any idea on how this could be done?
By that I guess I would need to return a book with also a rating entity.

Comment: @Kristjan You can just replace the `Where` clause above with `FirstOrDefault(b => b.Isbn == isbn && b.rating != null)`